# Improving performance of comparing file column to array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, performance, awk, comparison

I am comparing rows in a series of files against an array of floats in bash. Briefly, the files in question (../summarize_eigenvectors/"$xct"_*/*-5_1-sorted.txt) have the following structure

```
    c    v    weight        ik        kx        ky        kz
    1    1   0.00000         1   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
    1    1   0.00000         2   0.00000   0.04167   0.00000
    1    1   0.00000         3   0.00000   0.08333   0.00000
```

and the array is generated from ../vici_absdipole_noeh/v1c5.data, which has the following format:

```
kx      ky      kz          ik    ic    iv    is    ec (eV)         ev (eV)        eig (eV)   abs(dipole)^2      Re(dipole)      Im(dipole)
0.00000 0.00044 0.00000      1     1     1     1  0.11713703E+01 -0.12426462E+01  0.24140165E+01  0.69913425E-04  0.81359347E-02  0.19287282E-02
0.00000 0.01883 0.00000      2     1     1     1  0.11760590E+01 -0.12490846E+01  0.24251436E+01  0.59405512E-04 -0.70114501E-03  0.76755396E-02
0.00000 0.03722 0.00000      3     1     1     1  0.11746489E+01 -0.12612625E+01  0.24359113E+01  0.37648401E-04 -0.46637404E-02  0.39872204E-02
0.00000 0.05561 0.00000      4     1     1     1  0.11868220E+01 -0.12787400E+01  0.24655620E+01  0.18552618E-04 -0.21585915E-02  0.37273450E-02
```

What my code does is to compare the integers in the 4th column of the file v1c5.da against my array; if for a row of the file, the 4th column element is in the "list" array, then values of the file index, weight, ik, kx and ky in that row are echoed out.

Here's a sample of my working code, which compares 7485 files that has 1152 lines each to an array of 1152 elements

```
#!/bin/bash

#generates the array from information given in another file
for i in range $(seq 2 1153)
do
    ik=$(awk -v i=$i 'NR==i''{ print$4 }'  ../vici_absdipole_noeh/v1c5.data)
    dp2=$(awk -v i=$i 'NR==i''{ print$11 }'  ../vici_absdipole_noeh/v1c5.data)
    dp2f=$(printf "%.8f" $dp2)
    if (( $(echo "$dp2f > 6" |bc -l) )); then
        list+=("$ik" )
    fi
done

echo "xct   ik  weight  kx  ky" > v1c5-high_dp2_kpts.txt

task(){
    echo working on $xct
    for line in {1..1152};do
        weight=$(awk -v line=$line 'NR==line''{ print$3 }'  ../summarize_eigenvectors/"$xct"_*/*-5_1-sorted.txt)
        ik=$(awk -v line=$line 'NR==line''{ print$4 }'  ../summarize_eigenvectors/"$xct"_*/*-5_1-sorted.txt)
        kx=$(awk -v line=$line 'NR==line''{ print$5 }'  ../summarize_eigenvectors/"$xct"_*/*-5_1-sorted.txt)
        ky=$(awk -v line=$line 'NR==line''{ print$6 }'  ../summarize_eigenvectors/"$xct"_*/*-5_1-sorted.txt)
        if [[ " ${list[@]} " =~ " ${ik} " ]]; then
            echo "$xct  $ik $weight $kx $ky" >> v1c5-high_dp2_kpts.txt
        fi
    done
}

for xct in {1..7485};do
((i=i%360)); ((i++==0)) && wait
task "$xct" &
done
wait
```

The code has run for 8 hours plus and has only processed 1700 files, which is rather slow. Is there any bottleneck in this code that's limiting its performance? And if there is, how can I improve it?

I'm running this on the high performance computing center node that has 24 cores per node, hence I've used parallelization as well to speed things up. Apparently this is still not enough.

Comment: `bash` is a horrible language for this kind of application. Do it in a programming language with more powerful data structures.

Comment: Running `awk` 4 times for each line is clear indication that this is the wrong language for the job.

Comment: Why doesn't the `for line in {1..1152}` loop use `$line`?

Comment: Those 4 awk commands could just be `read -r _1 _2 weight ik kx ky <(cat ../summarize_eigenvectors/"$xct"_*/*-5_1-sorted.txt)`

Comment: Why are you using `awk` if you just want the first line?

Comment: Also why are you reading all the files that match the wildcard if you just want the first line of the first file?

Comment: Hi Marmar, the for line in {1..1152} loop gets each of the 1152 lines for processing. so the indented commands are actually working on each of the 1152 lines, not just the first line. You are right that these lines can be streamlined to "ik=$(awk '{ print$4 }'  ../summarize_eigenvectors/"$xct"_*/*-5_1-sorted.txt)", but this does not affect anything.

Comment: How does it get each of the 1152 lines? It's processing the same line every time with `NR==1`

Comment: Is that supposed to be `NR==$line`?

Comment: Why don't you just do all the work in one `awk` invocation that processes all the lines?

Comment: Oh yes you are right! I made a mistake here

Comment: can you give an example on how to use one awk invocation for all lines?

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for why you should start over and do whatever you're trying to do in awk. If you ask a new question that includes a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `task` function is really inefficient. It rereads all the files 4 times each time through the loop, just to process one line. You can do all the work in one `awk` invocation.

```
task(){
    echo working on $xct
    cat ../summarize_eigenvectors/"$xct"_*/*-5_1-sorted.txt |
        awk -v list="${list[*]}" -v xct="$xct" '
            BEGIN {
                split(list, list_array); # split string list into array list_array at whitespace delimiters
                for (i in list_array) list_hash[list_array[i]] = 1 # associative array with $list elements as keys
            }
            {
            weight=$3; ik=$4; kx=$5; ky=$6;
            if (ik in list_hash) printf("%s  %s %s %s %s\n", xct, ik, weight, kx, ky)
            }' >> v1c5-high_dp2_kpts.txt
}
```

Comment: This is a massive improvement! I finished the job in less than a minute. Out of curiosity, can you elaborate on what the split command does? I'm having trouble comprehending the syntax, so I thought maybe it'll be good elaborate on this for other users reading this too. Many thanks!

Comment: It splits the string into the array using whitespace as the delimiters.

Comment: See [GNU Awk User's Guide - String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions)

Comment: I've just realized that bc in line 9 was not behaving correctly because of the exponentials in the v1c5.data file used to generate the "list" array. After adding line 8 to convert the exponentials to floats for bc, the task function starts crashing with the error message: "awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `8' for reading (No such file or directory)". The file '8' here does not seem related to any variables used in the awk. Any idea what's causing the crash?

Comment: ok the "8" in the error message turns out to be the item of the "list" array

Comment: That would happen if you left out the quotes around `${list[@]}`

Comment: The code now has what is presented in the question and the task function replaced with your answer. I didn't find any unquoted ${list[@]}

Comment: I don't think it's related to that problem, but I just realized that I was using `xct` where I should be using `list`.

Comment: Ah ok, this clears my previous confusion with the split command. But the error persists. I tried manually defining list by using <<list=("6" "7" "9")>>, and the error changes to 9

Comment: I see the problem. `"${list[@]}"` expands into multiple arguments, each re-quoted. Use `[*]` to expand it as a single argument

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Can you enlighten me on what this the significance of using * and using @ here?

Comment: `[@]` expands the array into separate words, each re-quoted. `[*]` expands the array into one word.

Comment: I see now. Brilliant! Thanks!